# Bivariate Mapping (running a single variable regression and mapping r-squared value)

Tags: statistics, mapping, geoda

I am hoping to produce a bivariate map displaying the correlation between two variables (specifically percent SNAP participation by county against several social variables). I would like to produce something similar to the bivariate maps produced in Geoviz Tool Kit, that can then be exported in a finished format with a scatter plot and map of R-squared values.

I have looked into GeoDa, but have been unable to figure this out.

Attached are examples of what I hope to produce from Geoviz ToolKit.

[image: Bivariate Map]
[image: with scatter plot]

Comment: Are you asking how to compute the R^2 values or how to map them once they are computed?

Comment: R is extremely powerful. I am using right now for a geostats class. It is open-source and incredibly powerful. It can found used in advanced research in private sector, academia, and government agencies. It will also read spatial data with additional packages, which are similar to libraries. You can also output maps and graphs.

Comment: May I also suggest running a GWR which will account for local variation for such non-stationarity variables.

Comment: I also suggest GWR, using SNAP as dependent and all other variables as independent.  I would first use OLS regression to weed out insignificant variables.  GWR tools are available in GeoDan, ArcGIS, and R, among others.